# Multiple image upload using php

Tags: php

I have a simple php script that allows users to upload photos. I'd like to know how to convert this script to enable user to upload multiple photos at the same time.

This is part of the php script:

```
if (isset($_FILES['images'], $_POST['album_id'])) {

    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"]));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['images']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES["images"]["size"]);
    $image_temp = addslashes($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);

    $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $ex = explode('.', $image_name);
    $image_ext = strtolower(end($ex));

    $album_id = $_POST['album_id'];
```

What changes do I need to make to this part to allow multiple uploads?
I know there should be a foreach loop in there somwhere but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: First of all, this isn't going to work as shown (`images[]` will become `$_FILES['images'][0]`); Second, `multiple="multiple"` is a nonsense attribute; Third, there's a million tutorials for this out there - see e.g. this: http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload (took me about 5 seconds to do a Google search for "multiple upload PHP")

Comment: First of all, I've looked at about 500,000 of those million tutorials and I'm still asking the question. Second, 200,000 of those 500,000 suggested the multiple="multiple" attribute. And third, if you're not going to help don't comment.

Comment: Don't tell me what to do; 500k people saying something doesn't make it so; and I've provided a link to a working solution.

Comment: And yes I've read that tutorial 3 times today.

Comment: @Mike Without telling people what you've tried first, we have to make the (often correct) assumption that you haven't tried anything and are asking someone to do your job for you. Believe me, there's quite a number of those kinds of people out there.

Comment: If someone ELSE can give me some suggestions I'd surely appreciate it. And one with some form validation unlike the tutorial suggested earlier.

Comment: New question, how do I delete my name from this site? That might be a little easier for you guys to answer..

Comment: @Mike Read my answer and that should help you. if it doesnt then specify which parts you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike here is a rough solution, I will not write the entire code here but I will explain the logic behind it.

You have 2 ways to go , one would be to name each and every field manually (which would mean that you are limited to the number of fields you add manually) or use an array. the only difference between these 2 methods are the way you "point" them to your php script. incase you use predefined name for every field then you can call them normally but if you use the array method then you would need to use a format like : `$_FILES['FIELDNAME']['#ID']` (#ID starts from 0 to the number of fields that are created - 1, so you can do a while and go through them all).

So you have your fields in the html page, and in the php page you would go through them using a for loop. so you can use your current php code for the single upload and then go through each and every field and upload them one by one. here is an example :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['FILENAME']); $i++){

// USE YOUR UPLOAD SCRIPT HERE AND MAKE SURE YOU REPLACE YOUR CURRENT FILENAME to $_FILES['FILENAME'][$i]

}
```

Comment: That explained it perfectly and it works. Thanks Ahoura.

Comment: youre welcome. if you feel like the answer is good enough please choose it as an answer