# Upload Images to database php

Tags: php

I have a doubt..
I´m doing in php a page to buy and sell cars, and I have a form that has 5 input files(one for each image). The question is: Do I have to do 5 times the same file to upload each image separately or with one file that executes the code for the 5 images it´s ok?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each files with an id from 1-5. Like this $_FILES['filename']['#id'] and then use a for loop to upload them from 1-5. Hope this helps. There is a similar question here. [Multiple image upload using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057789/multiple-image-upload-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

As smuhero has said above, but you could also edit your database to have 5 seperate fields (one for each picture) then if a picture is uploaded you could either store the image directly in the database (takes a lot of space as you have to convert the image to Base64 data and then insert) or leave the location of the picture in the field.

Of course you'd have to ensure that you securely protect against incorrect files being called by malicious users.

Comment: Hi liam-fd, I have a 5 separate fields, one for each picture in my database. Another question, the id i will asign to each picture, is from html or php?

Comment: The ID will be from the HTML form that you generate. Each upload div or block should have a seperate ID.

Such as:
    <input type="upload" id="picture1" value="pic1" name="pic1">
    <input type="upload" id="picture2" value="pic2" name="pic2">

Comment: how would it be the for? the for has to be after the isset of the button?